# covering gr. house crops during extreme cold

Tags: greenhouse

I've grown greens in a gr. house for 22 years.  During extreme cold I've put the fabric from Dewalt over hoops. In extreme cold I have 6-8 of these covers on but the next day I have to dry these covers due to condensation which takes most of the day.  Could I put plastic over the hoops first, then the fabric cover on top eliminating the drying of fabric the next day without damaging the plant? We're headed for some extreme weather starting tonight, thank you.

Comment: Not sure to understand. Condensation is not so bad. It keep some humidity on the green house (and it keep more heat). I would make something, if there is too much mold/rot (which sometime it happens).